# Laravel form request validation check realtion between two fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-8

i need to make sure that two fields from a json passed by a post API are in a specific relation.
For Example, if the value of FieldA is 80, the fieldB must be 02 to pass the validation.

I'm using laravel: "^8.12",

This is my code from TestRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'fieldA' => ['required', Rule::in(['80', '82', '88', '91'])],
        'fieldB' => IF fieldA IS 80 MUST BE 00, OTHERWISE 02,
    ];
}
}
```

How can i archieve that?

Comment: have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: i tried to create a costum rule for the second field but i can't access to the first field value.

Comment: okay, show what you have attempted then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider doing like below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'fieldA' => ['required', Rule::in(['80', '82', '88', '91'])],
        'fieldB' => [
            function (string $attribute, mixed $value, $fail) {
                if ($this->fieldA == 80) {
                    if ($value != '00') {
                        $fail('The field B have to be 00 when fieldA is 80');
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($value != '02') {
                        $fail('The field B have to be 02 when fieldA isn`t 80');
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    ];
}
```

For nested array, you can consider doing:

```
return [
    'arr1.*.arr2.*.fieldA' => ['required', Rule::in(['80', '82', '88', '91'])],
    'arr1.*.arr2.*.fieldB' => [
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, $fail) {
            $flafttenKey = str_replace('arr.', '', $attribute);
            $flafttenKey = str_replace('.fieldB', '.fieldA', $flafttenKey);

            $fieldA = Arr::get($this->arr, $flafttenKey);

            if ($fieldA == 80) {
                if ($value != '00') {
                    $fail('The field B have to be 00 when fieldA is 80');
                }
            } else {
                if ($fieldA != '02') {
                    $fail('The field B have to be 02 when fieldA isn`t 80');
                }
            }
        },
    ]
];
```

Comment: Hi, i think this is the answer i was looking for. Thanks
Before close the post i would ask how it will works in a more complex situation:

'arr1.*.arr2.*.fieldA'
'arr1.*.arr2.*.fieldB'